# Commpossed percentage over same base

Tags: calculus, arithmetic, percentages

Maybe this sounds a Little trivial.

I have a value and Over this value apply percentage (a), then over this result apply other percentage (b)
Could say :

Value = 145760 
a= 8% 
b= 40%

My actual calcs 
R1= 145760 * (1-a)
R2= R1 * (1-b)

My question:  there is a math rule that allow me to simplify the percentage to apply in one step.

My needs: I have a program that allow me to enter a single porcentaje then  I need to get the percentage that matchs with my calcs with only one variable actually must do it by testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the thing you asked for but you could substitute R1 in R2 and get R2 = 145760 * (1-a) * (1-b) -> 145760 * c and your c is (1-a) * (1-b) other then that there probably won't be a way to simplify your task.

Comment: You  have the reason. so simple Some times we can see the sun the sun because of our black glasses. Very tks